# my javascript to get element by id is working on one line but not on the other

Tags: javascript

i am loading a page for my pending orders in view and displaying the data in a table i am calculating line total through javascript and it is going well but when i try to show in the page there is error in getting the element by its id and is the error is: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

```
 <div class="ziehharmonika">
 <?php if( count($pending_orders) ): ?>
 <?php foreach ($pending_orders as $info): ?>
<h3 id="header3" style="background-color: #00bad3; color:white;" 
    onclick="get_line_total(<?php print_r($info['id']);?>);"><span 
    style="color: black;">order# </span> <?php print_r($info['id']);?> 
    Status: </span> <span id="status<?php print_r($info['id']);?>"><?php 
    print_r($info['status']);?></span></h3>
<div class="w3_agile_recipe-grid"> 
    <section>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="ordertable" 
    id="ordertable<?php print_r($info['id']);?>">

      <tr>
        <th>Sr_No</th> <!-- Dummy cell for the row number and row commands 
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>item_Name</th>
        <th>price</th>
    <th>company</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
        <th>line_total</th>
      </tr>

<?php if( count($info['porders']) ): ?>
<?php

 $row_count = 1;
foreach ($info['porders']as $order_info){ ?> 
<tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_count; ?></td> <!-- Don't remove this column 
        as it's needed for the row commands -->
        <td class="ord_id"><?php print_r($order_info['id']);?></td>
    <td><?php print_r($order_info['name']);?></td>
        <td class="ord_price"><?php print_r($order_info['price']);?></td>
    <td><?php print_r($order_info['company']);?></td>
    <td class="ord_qty"><?php print_r($order_info['quantity']);?></td>
    <td class="line_total"></td>
      </tr>
   <?php $row_count++; }?>

    </table>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php endif;?> 

<div><span>Total Amount</span><p id="tota<?php 
    print_r($order_info['id']);?>"></p></div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </section>
    </div>
    </div>
```

my javascript is;

```
   var get_line_total = function(id){
   var table = document.getElementById('ordertable'+id);
   ord_price=0;
   ord_qty=0;
   linetotal=0;
    for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {

      ord_price = parseInt(table.rows[r].cells[3].innerHTML);
      ord_qty = parseInt(table.rows[r].cells[5].innerHTML);
      linetotal= ord_price * ord_qty;
  table.rows[r].cells[6].innerHTML = linetotal;
    }

    ord_total=0;
    for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {

      ord_total = ord_total + parseInt(table.rows[r].cells[6].innerHTML);

    }
    // this line is giving above said error
document.getElementById('tota'+id).innerHTML = ord_total;

    }
```

can any body help me to correct this code and get rid of the error

Comment: seeing your php code is not at all helpful without seeing the rendered output that the JavaScript is actually working with.

Comment: sorry actually the problem was with id of the span "tota". i was using <?php  print_r($order_info['id']);?> to add the number but in fact i had to use  <?php 
    print_r($info['id']);?> so when i used this there was no error . i spent three days to get the answer and when i was disappointed and was thinking to abandon it but luckily i noticed my mistake.